# Untappd API - getting beer's rating

Tags: jquery, untappd

i am building a wp plugin that uses untappd API.

When i search for beer, ex.budweiser, i get response object, 
in each beer rating is 0(i look at auth_rating, don't see any other 'rating' option).

If i go to Untappd.com, ex. - https://untappd.com/search?q=budweiser&type=beer&sort=all 
You can see there are ratings.

Screenshot attached.

Why is it for every beer in the api rating is 0, but on site it is filled?

[image]

Comment: This would seem like a data issue with the API which you should send directly to Untappd. No one here is going to be able to answer why they aren't sending you that data

Comment: thanks rory, i believe there are devs who use untappd and SO - just like me, but i appreciate your opinion :)

Comment: I did try to tag your question with 'untappd' but it doesn't exist, so it's unlikely they are here. Plus with issues like this you're best to ask the devs directly.